Troubles with making a Favorite with Hive DB Flutter
I want to make a Sptotify Clone application. I pull songs from Firebase and the list is swapped when the data is pulled again. I use state management with Bloc. Here my coding page image.
Here is my song_tile_widget.dart code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'package:spotify_clone_app/core/repository/model/songs/songs_model.dart';

class SongTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Song> songs;

  const SongTile({required this.songs, super.key});

  @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ValueListenableBuilder<Box<Song>>(
    valueListenable: Hive.box<Song>('favorite').listenable(),
    builder: (context, box, _) {
      return Column(
        children: List.generate(songs.length, (index) {
          final song = songs[index];
          final isFavorite = box.get(song.id) != null;
          return ListTile(
            leading: ClipOval(
              child: Image.network(
                song.imageUrl,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
                  return const CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                    child: Icon(Icons.music_note, color: Colors.red),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            title: Text(song.title),
            subtitle: Text(song.artist),
            trailing: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                isFavorite ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
                color: isFavorite ? Colors.red : null,
              ),
              onPressed: () async {
                if (isFavorite) {
                  await box.delete(song.id);
                } else {
                  await box.put(song.id, song);
                }
              },
            ),
          );
        }),
      );
    },
  );
}

}

When I press the favorite button, the favorite icons of all songs change to the favorite icon and are not added to the favorite list.
Here is my Home Page:
import 'package:auto_route/auto_route.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:spotify_clone_app/app/views/view_home/view_model/home_event.dart';
import 'package:spotify_clone_app/app/views/view_home/view_model/home_state.dart';
import 'package:spotify_clone_app/app/views/view_home/view_model/home_view_model.dart';
import 'package:spotify_clone_app/app/views/view_home/widgets/home_top_card_widget.dart';
import 'package:spotify_clone_app/app/views/view_home/widgets/play_list_widget.dart';
import 'package:spotify_clone_app/app/views/view_home/widgets/song_search_delegate_widget.dart';
import 'package:spotify_clone_app/app/views/view_home/widgets/song_tile_widget.dart';
import 'package:spotify_clone_app/core/constants/color_constants.dart';
import 'package:spotify_clone_app/core/extensions/context_extension.dart';
import 'package:spotify_clone_app/core/widgets/app_bar.dart';
import 'package:spotify_clone_app/core/widgets/drawer_widget.dart';
import 'package:spotify_clone_app/gen/assets.gen.dart';

@RoutePage()
class HomeView extends StatelessWidget {
  HomeView({super.key});

  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => HomeViewModel()..add(HomeInitialEvent()),
      child: BlocBuilder<HomeViewModel, HomeState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          return Scaffold(
            key: _scaffoldKey,
            appBar: _buildAppBar(context, state),
            endDrawer: const DrawerWidget(),
            body: _buildBody(context, state),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  BasicAppbar _buildAppBar(BuildContext context, HomeState state) {
    return BasicAppbar(
      hideBack: true,
      onPressed: () {},
      title: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
            onPressed: () {
              showSearch(
                context: context,
                delegate: SongSearchDelegate(state.songs ?? []),
              );
            },
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: SvgPicture.asset(
                Assets.images.svg.spotifyLogo,
                height: context.mediumValue,
                width: context.highValue,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context, HomeState state) {
    if (state.songs == null) {
      return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    } else if (state is HomeErrorState) {
      return Center(child: Text(state.message));
    }

    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          const HomeTopCardWidget(),
          context.sizedHeightBoxNormal,
          _buildSongList(context, state),
          _buildPlayList(context, state),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSongList(BuildContext context, HomeState state) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: context.mediumValue),
      child: SizedBox(
        width: context.width,
        height: context.height * .30,
        child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: state.songs!.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final song = state.songs![index];
            return Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: context.lowValue),
              child: SizedBox(
                width: context.width * 0.4,
                child: Stack(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  children: [
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.circular(context.mediumValue * .7),
                            child: Image.network(
                              song.imageUrl,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
                                return const Icon(Icons.music_note);
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        context.sizedHeightBoxLow,
                        Text(
                          song.title,
                          style: Theme.of(context)
                              .textTheme
                              .bodyLarge
                              ?.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          maxLines: 1,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          song.artist,
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium,
                          maxLines: 1,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      bottom: context.height * 0.038,
                      left: context.width * 0.24,
                      child: IconButton(
                        icon: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius:
                                  BorderRadius.circular(context.mediumValue),
                              color: AppColors.darkBackground),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(context.lowValue),
                            child: Icon(Icons.play_arrow,
                                size: context.width * 0.1,
                                color: AppColors.lightBackground),
                          ),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {},
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildPlayList(BuildContext context, HomeState state) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: context.mediumValue),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          PlayListWidget(
            showSeeMore: state.showSeeMore,
            onSeeMorePressed: () {
              context.read<HomeViewModel>().add(SeeMoreEvent());
            },
            text: state.showSeeMore ? 'See Less' : 'See More',
            onSeeLessPressed: () {
              context.read<HomeViewModel>().add(SeeLessEvent());
            },
          ),
          AnimatedContainer(
            duration: context.durationMedium,
            height: state.showSeeMore ? null : context.highValue * 5,
            child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: state.showSeeMore ? state.songs!.length : 3,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final song = state.songs![index];
                return SizedBox(
                    width: context.width,
                    child: SongTile(
                      songs: [song], // Tek bir şarkı nesnesi geçiyoruz     
                    ));
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

}
and here my view model code:
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:spotify_clone_app/app/views/view_home/view_model/home_event.dart';
import 'package:spotify_clone_app/app/views/view_home/view_model/home_state.dart';
import 'package:spotify_clone_app/core/repository/model/songs/songs_model.dart';

class HomeViewModel extends Bloc<HomeEvent, HomeState> {
  HomeViewModel() : super(HomeLoadingState()) {
    on<HomeInitialEvent>(_initial);
    on<SeeMoreEvent>(_seeMore);
    on<SeeLessEvent>(_seeLess);
    on<SearchEvent>(_search);
  }

  final FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

Future<void> _initial(HomeInitialEvent event, Emitter<HomeState> emit) async {
  emit(HomeLoadingState());
  try {
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await firestore.collection('Songs').get();

    if (snapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) {
      List<Song> songs = snapshot.docs
          .map((doc) => Song.fromJson(doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>))
          .toList();
          

      // Debug output to check fetched songs and their image URLs
      for (var song in songs) {
        print("Fetched Song: ${song.id}, Title: ${song.title}, Image URL: ${song.imageUrl}");
      }

      songs.shuffle();
      emit(HomeLoadedState(songs: songs, filteredSongs: songs, showSeeMore: false));
    } else {
      emit(HomeLoadedState(songs: [], filteredSongs: [], showSeeMore: false));
    }
  } catch (e) {
    emit(HomeErrorState(message: "Unable to fetch songs. Please try again later."));
  }
}


  void _seeMore(SeeMoreEvent event, Emitter<HomeState> emit) {
    if (!state.showSeeMore) {
      emit(state.copyWith(showSeeMore: true));
    }
  }

  void _seeLess(SeeLessEvent event, Emitter<HomeState> emit) {
    if (state.showSeeMore) {
      emit(state.copyWith(showSeeMore: false));
    }
  }

  void _search(SearchEvent event, Emitter<HomeState> emit) {
    final query = event.query.toLowerCase();
    final filteredSongs = state.songs?.where((song) {
      final title = song.title.toLowerCase();
      final artist = song.artist.toLowerCase();
      return title.contains(query) || artist.contains(query);
    }).toList();

    emit(state.copyWith(filteredSongs: filteredSongs ?? []));
  }
}

How can I add them to the favorite list with their id values and then send them to the favorite page? Can you help me?
